# Why does the CRT return an 8 byte leak if strings are used in main?

Tags: c++, windows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC

using namespace std;

int main(void){
    string file = "hello";
    string foo;
    char response;

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG);

    return 0;
}
```

Just a small self contained example. The console will read:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{143} normal block at 0x007DAE50, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <  B     > 18 FB 42 00 00 00 00 00 
{142} normal block at 0x007DAE08, 8 bytes long.
 Data: << B     > 3C FB 42 00 00 00 00 00
```

After running. Is this an issue with CRT not handling strings properly?

Comment: Not a windows dev, but a guess: is it because you call those functions before the strings have gone out of scope?

Comment: Nice guess. Moved the _CrT calls above the string declarations, and the leaks vanished. Wanna format that as an answer and I'll give you the check? It is odd behaviour though, since all the _CRT calls are doing are setting flags to check for leaks as the program quits. Where they're set shouldn't (to my understanding) effect their analysis of leaks at quit-time.

Comment: Well, it seems that `_CrtSetDbgFlag` and `_CrtSetReportMode` are for quit time, but `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` dumps the state of the leak checker right away.  Because you still have memory that hasn't been freed, it thinks there's a leak.  So you can set the flags and report mode wherever you want, but only call _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks when you think everything should already have been released.

Comment: Yups, good calls. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you call `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` before `main` has returned, so the strings haven't yet gone out of scope.  You should only check for leaks after the strings should have been freed, for example:

```
void myFunc() {
    string file = "hello";
    string foo;
    char response;
}

int main(void){

    myFunc();

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve it:

```
int main(void){
{
  string file = "hello";
  string foo;
  char response;
} // file's destructor called here

_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
_CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG);

return 0;
```

}

bacause the strings will otherwise only be deleted at the end of the `main` function, and will thus be still in the scope (and therefore own heap-memory) when the `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` function is called.

Answer (score 1):

```
_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
```

You are asking for a leak report *before* the string destructors could run.  Putting curly braces around code before this statement would be a workaround.

But you are simply helping too much, it already generates a leak report after main() returns.  So just delete the statement.  And add, say, `auto leak = new int;` so you see a real leak.